# Linked List Return Value

Tags: java

I was solving a Leetcode problem regarding the linked list. I am wondering why a return value has to be `head` instead of `result` in below code.

```
Input: 1->1->2
Output: 1->2
```

If I return a result, output is `2`.

```
public static ListNode deleteDuplicates(ListNode head) {
    ListNode result = head;

    if (head == null)
        return head;
    // System.out.println(listNodetoString(result));

    while (result.next != null) {
        if (result.val == result.next.val)
            result.next = result.next.next;
        else
            result = result.next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: We have to return the head to get the complete List after deleting the duplicates

Comment: Because returning the tail of a linked list isn't helpful?

Comment: since you do ListNode result = head; result is just another reference to head and lines result.next= result.next.next is the same as you would use  head.next, you can spare result variable anddo everything with head

Comment: It's the sort of method that doesn't really need a return value at all, IMHO, but returning the head lets you then turn around and chain other methods. Returning the result is kind of random.

Comment: `result` is a poor and, as we can see, misleading name. It's not the result of anything, it's just a temporary variable used to traverse the list. Better names would be `node` or `temp`.

Comment: As an aside: "*`if (result.val == result.next.val)`*" - if `val` is not a primitive, this will get you in some trouble. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood well your question what is troubling you is mutability (and pointers)
Given your method:

```
public static ListNode deleteDuplicates(ListNode head) {
    ListNode result = head;

    if (head == null)
        return head;
    // System.out.println(ListNodetoString(result));

    while (result.next != null) {
        if (result.val == result.next.val)
            result.next = result.next.next;
        else
            result = result.next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

(simplified response),
the memory, at the beginning of the method, contains just the `head` pointer to the list:

```
         1-next->1-next->2
         ↑
head:----┘
```

when you do:

```
ListNode result = head;
```

you're creating a pointer to the same value as head is pointing, like:

```
         1-next->1-next->2
         ↑
head:----┘
result:--┘
```

Then you start iterating the list, and the branches of the if condition cause different effects.
When `result.val == result.next.val` is true you modify the internal state of the `ListNode` using

```
result.next = result.next.next;
```

What it does, is changing the pointer of the list, as you are referencing the field `.next` of the value whom `result` is pointing, like:

```
                 1-next--┐
                         ↓ 
         1-----next----->2
         ↑
head:----┘
result:--┘
```

as result.next was changed, the 2nd node (the `1` in first line) is not referenced anymore by any pointer.
Then your `while` start again, having the if condition false, at this point the method does:

```
result = result.next;
```

In this way you are changing what `result` is pointing to, like:

```
           1-next┐
                 ↓ 
         1-next->2
         ↑       ↑
head:----┘       |
result:----------┘
```

So when you return `head` you are returning the value `head` is pointing to, the first element of the list. Meanwhile during the iteration `result` change each time the if return a false, going on if your initial list was:

```
1-next->1-next->2-next->3
```

The next iteration would change result again like:

```
           1-next┐
                 ↓ 
         1-next->2-next->3
         ↑               ↑
head:----┘               |
result:------------------┘
```

But `head` always remain to the top element.
The fact is that you don't need a return value, for what I understood from your code, it would works also as:

```
public static void deleteDuplicates(ListNode head) {
    ListNode result = head;

    if (head == null)
        return;
    // System.out.println(listNodetoString(result));

    while (result.next != null) {
        if (result.val == result.next.val)
            result.next = result.next.next;
        else
            result = result.next;
    }
}
```

Then you can try it with something like:

```
ListNode list = new ListNode(1, new ListNode(1, new ListNode(2, null)));
deleteDuplicates(list);
System.out.println(listNodetoString(list));
```

That's because in this way `list` is pointing also to the first value of the list, so at the beginning of the method the memory is something like:

```
list:----┐
         ↓
         1-next->1-next->2
         ↑
head:----┘
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean method for that is :

```
 public static ListNode deleteDuplicateas(ListNode head) {

    while (head != null) {
        if (head.val == head.next.val)
            head.next = head.next.next;
        else
            head= head.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (head.val == head.next.val)` is still a smell. Furthermore, this code will not compile since a return statement is missing. And speaking of clean code... I wonder why a method called `delecteDuplicateas(...)` needs a return value and what is actually returned...

Comment: That doesn't even compile.

Comment: come on just make void output, is not big deal